# Ingesting key-value pairs gets transformed to key-array-of-values in ElasticSearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

Ingesting:

```
{"key": value}
```

ends up becoming:

```
{"key": [value]}
```

in ElasticSearch (0.9 as well as 1.x)

Comment: it does not by default: ``$ curl localhost:9200/so/keyvalue/1 -d '{"key": "value"}'
{"_index":"so","_type":"keyvalue","_id":"1","_version":1,"created":true}; $ curl localhost:9200/so/keyvalue/1                      
{"_index":"so","_type":"keyvalue","_id":"1","_version":1,"found":true, "_source" : {"key": "value"}}``; might be your [mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html)

Comment: Can we see A) your mapping and B) your actual index operation?